# How can I add one new Column in Oracle 11g with default value, but not apply default value to old records immediatly?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have an existing table with millions of records. Now I want to add a new column with default value. But for performances reasons I don't want to apply the new value immediately to existing records. Is there one handy way to do it?

So far, what in my mind is to work around this issue is to:

- Add the new column, but do not specify a default (DDL)
- Update by chunk the old rows to the default value (to avoid locking the table) (DML)
- COMMIT
- Alter the column to add a default (DDL)

Comment: You say that you don't want to set existing rows to have the default value initially.  But then your proposed workaround seems to include a step that updates all the existing rows to the default value.  I'm confused-- do you want the existing rows to have the default value or not?  Or are you saying that you want some existing rows to have the default value but not others?

Comment: @JustinCave I'm not sure, but I think it is _"add one new Column with default value, but not apply **immediately** default value to old record"_.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - If that's the case, then the "(not only for performance reason)" comment doesn't make sense to me.  Unless that's supposed to be "note: only for performance reasons" in which case the fact that adding a new non-NULL column with a default doesn't have to actually update the existing rows to assign the default value becomes hugely important.

Comment: @JustinCave Even if there was some "other reasons", I think the performance/locking issues are at the core of the question -- making it quite interesting.  I took the liberty to edit it to put more emphasis on that. Please, Waveletus, feel free to revert that edit or to edit further if you need to.

Comment: "*to avoid locking the table*" - an `UPDATE` will not lock "the table" - it will only lock the modified rows for other DML statement. You can still _read_ those rows (e.g. in a `select` statement)

Comment: I don't understand this question. When a new column is added even with a not null DEFAULT value, the existing rows will have NULL in this column. The update to set the NULL rows to DEFAULT VALUE can be done whenever convenient.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. For the default value, I want to only apply to the new inserted record. For the existing record, I will update it to other value (example, not sysdate). I will back fill the old record based on some calculation (not the default sysdate).  For example: I have one table (id, col1) with two rows(1, 1) and (2,2). Now I added one new column col2(modified _date date). I want existing two record has null on col2. But if I insert another row, it will adopt the default value (3,3, 2015/5/30). For the existing record, I may just want to backfill the date to (2000/1/1).

Comment: @waveletus -  Adding the new column with a DEFAULT will NOT back fill the existing rows, and only new INSERTed rows will get the DEFAULT value. So, it seems it already does what you want. You can UPDATE any row (pre or post new column DEFAULT addition) with any value you like.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be

- Add the new column without any default value but make it accept
  `NULL`
- While inserting new record, insert `NULL` for this column
- CREATE a `AFTER INSERT` trigger and update the column with it's
  default value.

Something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update
AFTER INSERT
   ON table_name
BEGIN
UPDATE table_name 
SET new_column = (default_value)
WHERE Id_Column = :new.Id_Column;
END;
```

Comment: So for each insert you want to update the **whole** table over and over again?

Comment: I don't like trigger since it complicates the problem.